# How does one clear dig's DNS cache on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I'm trying to use dig to verify some DNS information, but I'm only seeing old results. From what I've read, Ubuntu doesn't cache DNS by default at an OS level. If that's true, then the dig command has its own DNS cache. Presumably, installing a universal DNS cache like `nscd` would not prevent dig from using its own cache, so my question is how do I clear the cache used by the dig command?

I realize that DNS information may not propagate right away, but if I `dig @8.8.8.8` for example, I get updated results. However, using dig normally on the same domain multiple times will reveal that all results besides the first take 0ms, so clearly there is caching going on at some level.

Edit: Here is the summary from `dig superuser.com` on the first try:

```
;; Query time: 233 msec
;; SERVER: 208.109.188.1#53(208.109.188.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 24 10:09:19 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

and the second try:

```
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 208.109.188.1#53(208.109.188.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 24 10:09:58 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dig` has no cache of its own, unless you run some caching daemon locally such as `nscd` or `dnsmasq` etc. If you do you just need to restart these daemons to clear the local cache, you can use `+trace` to see exactly where the results are coming from.

Comment: If I use `+trace`, it skips the cache and gives me up-to-date results, so that doesn't help me figure out where the cache is. It does reinforce my knowledge of a cache though, since I can immediately try the request again without `+trace` and still get the old results. I've checked my running processes and checked whether every caching daemon I know of is installed and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: if you have a local cache, dig result should show the local loop ip 127.0.0.1 or something similar. what is the output of a plain dig that you are seeing?

Comment: Edit: I put the results in original question, since I can't do code blocks in comments.

Comment: caching does not seem to be done on your local system so you don't have local dns cache, but at your dns server.

Comment: If that's true, shouldn't a traced dig still give me the results cached on my DNS server?

Comment: seems it should. i have local dns cache and +trace has the cache server result included, but while tracing it may have updated its cache?

Comment: It seems that it was indeed the server. I switched my DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` to some with shorter cache lifetimes and now I get more up-to-date results. Thanks for your help. Upvote and accepted answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file, replace the line with another nameserver such as nameserver 8.8.4.4 and uninstall the package resolvconf (for Ubuntu: `apt-get remove resolvconf`). This worked for me.